# обнулить выбранное значение в dropdown после закрытия модального окна

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
После выбора конкретного значения в дропдаун и закрытии модального окна, при повторном открытии окна значение остается то, которое выбрал ранее. Т.е. при первом открытии значение "Кто покупал", при последующих открытиях этого окна отображается ранее выбранное значение(logins.selectedUser.email). как его **правильно** обнулить при закрытии окна, чтобы отображалось "Кто покупал"?
не могу понять, как погуглить это...

```
useEffect(()=>{
    fetchUsers().then(data=>logins.setUser(data))
}, [])
return (
    <Modal
        show={show}
        onHide={onHide}
        centered
    >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                Добавить расходы
            </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
            <Form>
                <Dropdown id="customersChoice" className="mt-2 mb-2"  hidden={true}>
                    <logins.selectedUser.email || "Кто покупал"}</Dropdown.Toggle>
                    <Dropdown.Menu>
                        {logins.user.map(customers =>
                            <Dropdown.Item
                                onClick={() => logins.setSelectedUser(customers)}
                                key={customers.email}
                            >
                                {customers.email}
                            </Dropdown.Item>
                        )}
                    </Dropdown.Menu>
                </Dropdown>
            </Form>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="outline-danger" onClick={onHide}>Закрыть</Button>
            <Button variant="outline-success" onClick={addAmount}>Добавить</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
```

Comment: Запоминается где? Что вы получаете сейчас и какого поведения хотите добиться? Дополните ваш вопрос ожидаемым поведением

Comment: SwaD, спасибо, добавил описания

Answer (score 0):

не особо раобрал, но если речь про это `logins.selectedUser.email || "Кто покупал"`, то как бы надо обнулить значение в `logins.selectedUser.email` при закрытии модалки что бы сработал втарой вариант, и кстати что это за либа, там так передается дофолтное значение?

Comment: react-bootstrap, элемент dropdown. я не могу понять какое там дефолтное значение(

Answer (score 0):

Видимо тут в onHide модального окна надо добавить функцию в которой как раз будет обнуляться значения:

```
<Modal    
   onHide={() => {
      logins.setSelectedUser(null);
      onHide();
   }}
/>
```

Comment: не обнуляется. причем при тапе вне модального окна выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: logins.selectedUser is not a function

Comment: Тогда нужно знать откуда берется у вас logins и что там лежит. Очень странная ошибка так как внутри модалки этот метод используется нормально вроде как.